# Hide or show field based on another selected field value in Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a number field in powerapps (app from a SharePoint list) that I only want to show if the selected value in in `Soort-Datacard2` is "Brandstof".

I use this formula for Visible in Powerapps:

```
If(Soort_DataCard2.Selected.Value="Brandstof";true;false)
```

This formula results in an invalid argument type. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the card named `Soort_DataCard2`, that probably has another control inside it you want to refer to.

It is probably named `DataCardValueX` with a unique number at the end:

[image]

Here, "Branch" is a Choice column.

Once you have found the right control, enter this in the `Visible` property of the card you want to show or hide:

[image]

You do not need the IF statement, as this returns a boolean (true/false) value by itself.